# Check if swf url avaliable or not using php get_headers Content-Type

Tags: php, string, content-type, get-headers

I'm trying to drop invalid URLs from my flash games site. 
Here is my code:

```
function valid($URL1) {
$headers = get_headers($URL1);
$headers = substr($headers[8],38,5);//leaves only flash word 
if ($headers=='flash')
return true; else   return false;
}
$URL1='http://www.ht83.com/medias/media-16/ht83com-cde-house-decoration.swf';
if(valid($URL1))
echo 'SWF are word>' ;
```

that code return true even Content-Type are not swf .

by the way I already tried

```
$headers=$headers['Content-Type'];
```

but give me no result .
When I tried

```
var_dump($headers);
```

return this for valid SWF URL
http://www.ht83.com/medias/media-16/ht83com-spongebob-squarepants-gone-fishing.swf

> array(9) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(35) "Date:
>   Sat, 01 Feb 2014 01:36:35 GMT" [2]=> string(144) "Server:
>   Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8m DAV/2
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
>   mod_fcgid/2.3.5" [3]=> string(20) "Accept-Ranges: bytes" [4]=>
>   string(22) "Content-Length: 342771" [5]=> string(39) "Cache-Control:
>   max-age=62208000, public" [6]=> string(38) "Expires: Mon, 03 Mar 2014
>   01:36:35 GMT" [7]=> string(17) "Connection: close"  [8]=> string(43)
>   "Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash" }

AND this for the Invalid SWF URL 
http://www.ht83.com/medias/media-16/ht83com-cde-house-decoration.swf

> array(12) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(35) "Date:
>   Sat, 01 Feb 2014 01:40:06 GMT" [2]=> string(144) "Server:
>   Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8m DAV/2
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
>   mod_fcgid/2.3.5" [3]=> string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.16" [4]=>
>   string(38) "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT" [5]=> string(77)
>   "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0,
>   pre-check=0" [6]=> string(16) "Pragma: no-cache" [7]=> string(62)
>   "Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=359cf391842876b3cc79066dcc3a08f4; path=/" [8]=>
>   string(21) "Vary: Accept-Encoding" [9]=> string(52) "Cache-Control:
>   max-age=600, private, must-revalidate" [10]=> string(17) "Connection:
>   close" [11]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html" }

So their is any easier way to get correct Content-Type of URL .

**Looks like I used get_headers() in numeric only . this code from Sean Johnson works**

```
function valid($URL) {
$headers = get_headers($URL, 1);//
return stripos($headers['Content-Type'],"application/x-shockwave-flash")!==false;
}
```

Comment: this this correct function function valid($URL) {
    $headers = get_headers($URL,1);
    return stripos("flash",$headers['Content-Type'])!==false;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the very first example of the [get_headers documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#example-4085) you need to use the second argument if you want to be able to access the header by it's key value.

Try this:

```
function valid($URL) {
    $headers = get_headers($URL,1);
    return stripos($headers['Content-Type'],"flash")!==false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code work perfect except minor fix with "flash" it should looks like . 
"application/x-shockwave-flash" Now the function work correctly :)

Comment: I've edited the code so that it finds "flash" anywhere in the header. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming that the Content-Type header will always be the 9th header returned by the server, which is not the case.

You will need to loop through the headers and examine only the correct one (that is, the one that starts with `Content-Type:`).